# sql daily, weekly , yearly reports for different product?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have a requirement to do a sale analysis weekly report
out put should like below

**yearly:**

```
product_name      week1_date         week2_date        week3_date     week4_date ''''
    name1            8                   40                0               0
    name2            2                   42                2               0
    name3            5                   47                1               0
```

**my schema is**

***product***

```
id
sys_sku
desc
selling_price
cost_price
supplier_id
```

***sale***

```
id
product_id
sold_to 
date
quantity
desc
```

i want to group to do sum(quantity) group by date distinct product

any help will be appreciable

Comment: Sqlite doesn't have a native datetime type, nor a built in pivot so it won't be totally straight forward

Comment: can we do this into any other db , postgres

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna answer cos it's a bit long for a comment but it's more of a hint than an answer.

It kinda depends *exactly* what your requirements are. You could query using a single date parameter and find the next x weeks / months etc using a Case..When statement

Assuming you store your datetime using the julian type then you can work with whole days and your sql looks a bit like this (pseudo sql)

```
Select product_id, case when date between inputDate and inputDate + 7 then quantity end as week1, case when date between inputDate + 7 and inputDate + 14 then quantity end as week2 from sale where date between inputDate and inputDate + x
```

You can then group by sum or calculate sales accordingly